# "Manager isn't accessible via model instances" when add data on ForgeinKey from ManyToManyField data

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In models:

```
class MyTeam(models.Model):
    captain_first_team = models.ForeignKey(FirstTeamPlayer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="captain_first_team_set")
    team_player_first_team = models.ManyToManyField(FirstTeamPlayer, blank=True, related_name="team_player_first_team_set")
```

In views:

```
amar_team = get_object_or_404(MyTeam, pk=team_id)
first_team_player = get_object_or_404(amar_team.team_player_first_team, pk=player_id)
amar_team.objects.create(captain_first_team=first_team_player)
```

Here, In `MyTeam` model I have a ManyToManyField field and a ForeignKey field. I want to add data in a ForeignKey field from ManyToManyField field data.

I also try:

```
amar_team.captain_first_team.add(first_team_player)
amar_team.captain_first_team.save(first_team_player)
```

But it's not working. How can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you can *not* access the `.objects` through a model *instance8. Only through a model class.

So you should define this as:

```
MyTeam.objects.create(captain_first_team=first_team_player)
```

and not through <s>`amar_team.objects.create(...)`</s>.

Based on your comments however, you want to update the `captain_first_team` of the `amar_team`, so you can set the foreign key like:

```
amar_team = get_object_or_404(MyTeam, pk=team_id)
first_team_player = get_object_or_404(amar_team.team_player_first_team, pk=player_id)
amar_team.captain_first_team = first_team_player
amar_team.save()
```

Comment: Then it make a another queryset when I user `MyTeam`. See it carefully I need to add data in a specific queryset. That's why I use pk of that `MyTeam`.

Comment: @jhonarab: what do you mean with "add data in a specific queryset"? Querysets are not meant to inject data, these are used to retrieve data, or to update/delete data in bulk.

Comment: "update data on ForgeinKey from ManyToManyField data". Sir, in my question i clear it what i want to do. Please see it sir and help me please. I need it.

Comment: @jhonarab: then you set that attribute.